# Choose account for Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Say I have multiple Google accounts (A and B) on my Android 8 smartphone. I have already installed some apps in the past with account A and I'd like to continue using this account. But now somehow, when I open the app, it asks me to accept the terms of use with account B. If I decline, the app closes, so I can't switch accounts from within the app without accepting with account B, which I'd like to avoid. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into settings  → apps  → play store  → storage  → clear data.

Now when you open the play store, it will default to your primary account, where you have already accepted the terms and conditions.

Comment: Ah! Once you accidentally select an account from the account switcher inside the app, you're asked to accept the terms of use. If you decline, the app closes and additionally remembers the last "chosen" account. So no other way than clearing the app data after that. Looks like a huge design flaw to me.

Comment: @xehpuk glad it works now. Google probably doesn't look at accepting terms and conditions as a big deal....